# How to Get current NSDate same to simulator Date? iPhone Sdk

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get current date with adding device time zone but is show 1 hr late that original date. I thing , I am getting problem of DaylightSavingTime.
How to disable isDaylightSavingTime = FALSE .

here is the code, I have used..

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate Date];
NSTimeZone *currentTimeZon = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
if ([currentTimeZon isDaylightSavingTime]) 
{
    NSLog(@"East coast is NOT on DT");
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"East coast is on DT");  

}
NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [currentTimeZon secondsFromGMTForDate:currentDate];
NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [date timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];
NSLog(@"### Announcement gmtDate = %@",gmtDate);
```

I am getting time with 1 Hour difference, date is perfact.

Comment: There is only one NSDate for each moment (it doesn't matter where you are). If you want to print the date in a different Timezone use NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Ya, but I want generic function which will automatic changes according to the timezone change. there is a problem when isDaylightSavingTime = FALSE. so i want to set isDaylightSavingTime = TRUE but I cannot do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSCalendar, it understands time zones, daylight savings, etc.  As @albertamg says, NSDate is just the time since a reference at UTC (GMT), it has no other concept.